# Speech Recognition in python not working in linux

Tags: python, linux, speech-recognition

I am using linux mint 20 and what error i am getting is that when i run the function for speech recognition the function starts but there is not output always in listening mode.

Here is my code:

```
import speech_recognition as sr
print('Checking if the speech_recognition is working properly or not.')
def takecom():
    r = sr.Recognizer()
    with sr.Microphone() as source:
        print("\nListning....")
        audio = r.listen(source)
    try:
        print("Recognising....")
        text = r.recognize_google(audio, language='en-in')
        print(text)
    except Exception:  # For Error handling
        print("Network connection error ")
        return "none"
    return text

takecom()
print('speech_recognition worked successfully')
```

SYSTEM DETAILS

> Linux mint 20 64 bit
>
> python 3.8.5

and a very strange thing is happening when i speak my words and then unplug the mic then it recognises my voice.

anyone please help me.

Comment: A wild guess is that it's using the wrong microphone or something.

Comment: can you let me know how to improve it

Comment: bro when i speak and uplug the mic then it is working

Comment: In your audio settings > input, maybe the mic is muted?

Comment: I'm not familiar with this module, but shouldn

Comment: no bro my mic is not muted. It is working on chrome perfectly]